# pcall() ignores os.execute() error

Tags: error-handling, lua

I'm working on a error handling and it almost works, but fails on the most important step.

In this file, "KAImage.lua" I have an syntax error (`=` vs `==`) and when example function below

```
print(status, err = pcall(os.execute, "/System/Library/Frameworks/Kakao.framework/KAImage.lua"))
```

called it gives me error with traceback and right after it `true    true`, so means `pcall()` absolutely ignores exception.

Script execution doesn't stops and I can't really see where is the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code snippet has the syntax error, correct code should looks like below:

```
local status, err = pcall(os.execute, "/System/Library/Frameworks/Kakao.framework/KAImage.lua")
print(status, err)
```

I don't think that executing a Lua file using `os.execute` is a good idea.
It would work with proper shebang, but will spawn separate process(es).

IMO  that you need is `dofile(lua_file_name)`:

> Opens the named file and executes its contents as a Lua chunk. ... Returns all values returned by the chunk. In case of
>   errors, dofile propagates the error to its caller (that is, dofile
>   does not run in protected mode).

It is a job of pcall to catch errors, if you do need to catch error you may use code like below:

```
local chunk, err = loadfile(lua_file_name)
if not chunk then
    -- invalid Lua code, check err
    return
end
local ok, err = xpcall (chunk, debug.traceback))
if not ok then
    -- error was catched, err contains detailed stack info and error description
    return
end
-- success
```

Comment: Yes! Replacing `os.execute` with `dofile` worked flawlessly, thank you much. I didn't used it because it wasn't before, but my code changed hardly and I'm happy there is no need for workarounds now.

Answer (score 1):

`os.execute` doesn't raise any error when it fails to execute the command; it returns `nil` as the first value to signal an error along with some additional values, as [described in the manual](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-os.execute).